# Jenkins Pipeline script to check the website is up

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins pipeline code, I am trying test if a web site is available or not.

```
withEnv([
    "ipaddrs=$FINAL_IP",
    "appuri=http://$FINAL_IP:8080"
]){
    timeout(time: 15, unit: 'MINUTES') {
        waitUntil {
            try {         
               sh "curl -s --head  --request GET $appuri/gameoflife | grep '200 OK'"
               return true
            } catch (Exception e) {
               return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But even though the website is up, Jenkins pipeline is not able to understand the same and it keeps on running till 15 min and timing out

I have manually run curl from Jenkins node and I am able to get the response back when web site comes up. Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it would work if you would use `URL` instead of shell?

```
try {         
    new URL("$appuri/gameoflife").getText()
    return true
} catch (Exception e) {
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks  for the reply.No it's still getting timed-out after 15 min.But the website is up and I can get the response back from browser.

Comment: The issue is with my proxy environment variable. You are right it's working fine. Even the curl shell steps too working fine after fixing the proxy issue.